# Should the statement after "then" be followed with modals?

Tags: conditionals, modal-verbs

Consider the following:

> If you were to buy this, then ask me.

Or should it be:

> If you were to buy this, then you would need to ask me.

Is the use of *would* necessary here? If we go with the first one, doesn't it break the rules of conditional statements?

Or how would you construct the hypothetical structure of the following:

> If you want to buy this, let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If (something) then (result): if the thing is bought, *then* ask you about it? After it has been bought?

That doesn't accord with your final quote where the thing is not bought [merely wanted] and you can help with buying it.

For this structure,

> If you want to buy this, let me know,

telling you **precedes** buying. So it's

> If you were to buy this, you would have to have asked me [first].
>   If you were to buy this, you would have needed to ask me [first].

Comment: Thanks. I am asking about the hypothetical. For example: **If he were to buy this, I wouldn't talk to him.** ?

Comment: Right: then yes, you do need *would* (both my examples use *would*, as does Barrie's).

Comment: So the first one is *wrong*, right?

Comment: Yes, the first one is wrong. The conditional *if* clause needs to be followed by *would*.

Comment: Then how is this: *That’s just what I was looking for, even if it isn’t a threefold distinction for me personally.* Where is the second part of the *if* statement. Sounds fine to me, but cant untangle it grammatically.

Comment: It's omitted. "That's X. Even if it isn't Y, [then] it is X" (note the use of *is* in the if-clause though, so this is different)

Answer (score 3):

The first has no meaning. The second is possible, but in isolation it’s difficult to see quite how it would be used. More likely would be *If you wanted to buy this, then you would need to ask me*. Your final sentence would be a perfectly reasonable response to a potential buyer.